# how to get session or cookie value set in django, php, ruby in angular?

Tags: php, angularjs, ruby, django, cookies

I am trying to get a session and/or cookie value I set in django (although I don't see this being different across other languages like php or ruby).

I am trying to get this value with the following angular:

```
 var app = angular.module('edgeFeed', ['ngCookies']);

  app.controller('FeedController', function($http, $cookieStore) {
      self = this;
      
      console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('session_name'));
      console.log($cookieStore.get('cookie_name'));
```

In the console I get the output:

> null
>
> undefined

**How can I get the session or cookie value in angular?**

Comment: console.log(document.cookie); work for standard PHPSESSID you try it?

Comment: @Deep it prints out a CSRF cookie but no others.

Comment: Then other cookies is other type(?). I cant help here. Will wait answers.

Comment: check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax